# Scaling problem when plotting a graph in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to generate a bar graph in R, but as the y-axis values ​​are very close, there is no difference in the graph.
Can someone help me?

This is the data I use to generate the chart.

```r
rede <- c("Wifi", "Wifi(AB)", "Wifi(AB) + 4G(AB)", "Wifi(AB) + 4G(B)", "4G(AB)")
disp <- c(0.9981663483026838, 0.9979983253954591, 0.9983305230561498, 0.9981898613052699, 0.9980460877265795)
down <- c(16.062788868489800, 17.534669535778500, 14.624618028127900, 15.85681496583588, 17.116271515163100)
dados <- data.frame("Ref" = rede, "Disponibilidade" = disp, "Downtime" = down)
```

```
ggplot(dados) +
aes(
x = Ref,
fill = Disponibilidade,
weight = Disponibilidade
) +
geom_bar(position = "fill") +
scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", direction = 1) +
labs(
x = "Redes",
y = "Valores",
title = "Gráfico Disponibilidade"
) +
theme_minimal() +
theme(
plot.title = element_text(size = 18L,
                      face = "bold",
                      hjust = 0.5)
)
```

[image: Graph]

Comment: Please share the code you used to create the graph.

Comment: You might want to take a look at `coord_cartesian`

Comment: Help you with what exactly? If that's what your data is, then that's what it is—not much you can do to change the fact that there isn't much variance. Maybe you want to change to a different type of chart, but what kind you should use really depends on the context and purpose of the visualization and becomes subjective

Comment: Now that you've posted your code (albeit as an answer for now), I can see you've used `geom_bar`, which by default plots counts, not values. You've then reinforced that setting by adding `position = "fill"`, which makes sure that all bars stack up to 1. You haven't otherwise told ggplot to put anything else on the y-axis, and I'm not sure what you want on that axis anyway. Regardless, my question of what you're trying to change and whether it's a decision for us to make still applies

Comment: @camille
First of all thanks for your help :)
I would like the difference in y-axis values ​​to be more evident in the bars

Comment: @Dave2e
I just posted the code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As others mentioned in the comments, it's unclear what exactly you are looking for, but you could do something like this (as @JonathanV.Solórzano recommended with using `coord_cartesian`).

```
library(ggplot2) 

ggplot(dados) +
  aes(
    x = Ref,
    y = Disponibilidade,
    fill = Disponibilidade,
    weight = Disponibilidade
  ) +
  geom_col() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", direction = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(dados$Disponibilidade), max(dados$Disponibilidade))) +
  labs(x = "Redes",
       y = "Valores",
       title = "Gráfico Disponibilidade") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18L,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  hjust = 0.5))
```

Output

[image]

Alternative with `geom_bar` (which produces the same output as above)

```
ggplot(dados) +
  aes(
    x = Ref,
    fill = Disponibilidade,
    weight = Disponibilidade
  ) +
  geom_bar() +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(option = "plasma", direction = 1) +
  coord_cartesian(ylim = c(min(dados$Disponibilidade), max(dados$Disponibilidade))) +
  labs(x = "Redes",
       y = "Valores",
       title = "Gráfico Disponibilidade") +
  theme_minimal() +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 18L,
                                  face = "bold",
                                  hjust = 0.5))
```